# How to Render Api Data to Twig file using Angular js

Tags: php, angularjs, json, symfony, twig

what i need

- i need to render data in symfony2 twig file.
- some one has marked my question duplicate ,i need to render data using angular js not using symfony.

js code

```
function EntryCtrl ($scope, $http) {
$scope.rootEntry = [];
$http.get('https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos').success(function(root) {
    $scope.rootEntry = root;
    console.log($scope.rootEntry);
});
 }
```

output of variable $scope.rootEntry

data

```
 {
   id: 1,
    name: "afeef",
   price: "20",
   description: "this is test page"
},
{
 id: 2,
 name: "afeef",
 price: "20",
  description: "this is test page"
}
```

html code

```
 <body >
<div class="row" ng-controller="EntryCtrl">
 <---updated code -->
 # i have tried map model as well as
 <table ng-model="rootEntry">
  <div id="treeview" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="root in rootEntry">{{root.name}}</li>
        </ul>
   </div>
</table>
</div>
```

```
  Exception variable  rootEntry is does not exists
```

controller code

```
 public function checkAction()
 {
    $this->render('bundlename:twigfilename');
 }
```

- error rootentry doesnot exist
- i need to show json data in twig file

solution

```
    1. it can be done through symfony2 by rendering the json data through controller

    like $this->render('bundlename:twigfilename',array('rootEntry,['jsonstring']);
```

- but i need to make http request to send data in twig file
- im new in angular js any suggestion is most welcome

general way for angular rendering

```
  var mockDataForThisTest = "json=" + encodeURI(JSON.stringify([
   {
    id: 1,
    firstName: "Peter",
     lastName: "Jhons"},
 {
   id: 2,
   firstName: "David",
   lastName: "Bowie"}
 ]));


 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function PeopleCtrl($scope, $http) {

  $scope.people = [];

   $scope.loadPeople = function() {
    var httpRequest = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: mockDataForThisTest

    }).success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.people = data;
    });

};

}
```

html code

```
   <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
   <p>    Click <a ng-click="loadPeople()">here</a> to load data.</p>
   <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
    <td>{{person.id}}</td>
    <td>{{person.firstName}}</td>
    <td>{{person.lastName}}</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   </div>
   </div>
```

- but in this question how could i render data in twig through angular js.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change angular's interpolation markup. In fact, twig is using the same interpolation markup as angular: "{{ }}" that's why you had that error: twig is expecting a variable defined in your symfony controller.
To do so, you have to configure your application module:

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
}
```

Now, in your twig page use [[ ]] instead of {{ }}:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
      <p>    Click <a ng-click="loadPeople()">here</a> to load data.</p>
      <table>
          <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
              <td>[[person.id]]</td>
              <td>[[person.firstName]]</td>
              <td>[[person.lastName]]</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
```

I hope this will help you :)

P.S: for resolving $http promises use then instead of succes (it is deprecated)
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice

Answer (score 0):

For people with this problem in the future: you can use `{% verbatim %}`. It tells Twig to not process the code inside.

In the next code you have how to get Twig and Angular working together.

```
{{ max(1, 3, 2) }}  <<< The render is done by Twig
{% verbatim %}
<div ng-app="">
  <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
  Hello {{name}} <<< The render is done by Angular
</div>
{% endverbatim %}
```

More info in https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/215/how-to-use-angular-js-and-twig-without-the-conflict-of-double-curly-braces